# How can I get it to pick a random number from array but a different number each time?

Tags: python, arrays, random

I want to do a random pick from an array but not have the same number come up twice.

```
array = ['1','2','3','4',]
random.choice(array)
```

Right now it just picks a number, is there another way so that it will randomize but only do each number once?

Comment: just do `random.choice(array,size=3,replace=False)`if you want 3 different numbers for example

Comment: @fmarm Where did you get that usage from? It's not mentioned on https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Comment: @mkrieger, sorry, I am using the function `random.choice` from numpy, you should do `import numpy as np; np.random.choice(array,size=3,replace=False)`. Doc https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html

Answer (score 1):

A really easy way to do this would be to remove the choice from the list, after you choose it.

```
my_array = ['1','2','3','4']
x = random.choice(my_array)
my_array.remove(x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i put: ``` lottery = ['4753672', '3963852', '3092670', '9346897', '1234567', ] x = random.choice(lottery)``` and it prints x and then ```lottery.remove(x)``` this gives me the error "ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list"

Comment: You need to assign a value to x like this `x = random.choice(my_array)`

Comment: haha sorry i did that it just didn't format properly in the thing above. i have x = random.choice(lottery) (lottery is the array)